# Prevent function inlining

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I'm trying to shrink the compiled code size, and I have noticed that the compiler inlines functions a lot, even the ones I have not marked "inline", but I can't manage to turn that off.

It looks like the compiler uses the -Os flag by default (optimize for low program size), because when I add it, the resulting program size is the same.

I tried adding "__attribute__((noinline))" to the functions but it makes no difference. Any idea how to prevent function inlining?

I'm using Visualmicro on Visual Studio Community 2017. Arduino 1.8.8. Arduino Uno board.

Comment: Did you try  `__declspec(noinline)`? https://docs.microsoft.com/pl-pl/cpp/cpp/noinline?view=vs-2017

Comment: @FilipFranik That is only for Microsoft's compiler. Arduino uses GCC, which doesn't use Microsoft's custom cr@p.

Comment: @BjörnMorén How have you determined that it's inlining the functions?

Comment: See over on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244363/how-to-prevent-gcc-to-inline

Comment: Do you assume that not inlining a function shrinks the compiled code size? That might not be correct. The gcc compiler follows the -Os flag. Forcing to make a function call might increase the code size. You could show us your code, and we can shrink it. For an arduino uno, you could also move data from code to eeprom.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!

I created a class with a function with no arguments containing dummy code. Then I tried calling this function from the main() section, first one time and noted the size, then two times in a row and watched how it increased the compiled code size by 60 bytes. Then I applied the noinline attribute, and it made no difference. However, now when I do the same thing, the compiler behaves like it should. So my apologies for wasting your time with this.

Comment: But there is definitely something fishy going on with this compiler. Another test I did was to make all private variables public. Compiled code size shrunk, which is to be expected, since some optimizations could be made. Then I made them private again. Compiled size stayed at the shrunk size. It is as if the compiler needs a few tries to really optimize the code.

Comment: It is also weird how using the -Os flag still inlines functions even though they are not marked "inline". -Os means optimize for size. I can clearly tell it does this, because when I apply the noinline attribute to the functions, it makes my compiled code size smaller. I wish there was a compiler flag that meant "no inlining, except when the inline keyword is used".

Comment: What you call weird is in fact the extremely optimized code that the gcc compiler makes. The gcc can (almost) do whatever it wants. The "lto" optimization globally optimizes things, and the result is hard to predict. Sometimes variables are only temporary in registers and never occupy a memory location. There are options to control inlining: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html You can add them to a sketch with the #pragma. I took one of my larger sketches and tried a few inline options, but the code size never got smaller. Can you give a small sketch that becomes smaller?

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comments, I can't recreate this problem again. So I apologize for wasting everyone's time. But I still find it weird how the -Os flag works. I assumed it meant smallest possible size. But I now think it means "fairly small, but also make it run fast". Look at the code below, and how using the noinline attribute makes the code smaller. I added the -Os compiler flag to be sure, but I think it is already on by default.

```
class InlineClass
{
public:
    void __attribute__((noinline)) testFunc(int arg1)       // 570 bytes
    //void testFunc(int arg1)               // 602 bytes
    //inline void testFunc(int arg1)        // 602 bytes
    {
        _var1 = arg1 + 1;
        _var2 = arg1 + 2;
        _var3 = arg1 + 3;
        _var4 = arg1 + 4;
        _var5 = arg1 + 5;
    }

private:
    volatile int _var1 = 0;
    volatile int _var2 = 0;
    volatile int _var3 = 0;
    volatile int _var4 = 0;
    volatile int _var5 = 0;
};

void setup()
{
    InlineClass ic;
    ic.testFunc(1);
    ic.testFunc(2);
    ic.testFunc(3);
    ic.testFunc(4);
    ic.testFunc(5);
}
```

Comment: Did you check all the inline options in that link? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html The -Os turns on some them and the compiler uses heuristic to decide what to do. For example with the -finline-small-functions option. I get the 570 and 602 size for an arduino uno, that means you have found a miscalculation of the heuristic. That is an impressive achievement! I tried to turn the inline options off to be able to control it with a compiler option, but that did not work. When testFunc is made larger, the sizes are the same.

Comment: @Jot Thanks for the reply. I played around with the compiler flags relating to inline functions in the document you linked, but could not get it to work well. This is all a mystery to me, because when I selectively apply "__attribute__((noinline))" to certain functions in my sketch, I can shrink it by 578 bytes, from 32492 to 31914 bytes, which is a lot when you are close to the limit. Could it be that the compiler isn't properly tailored for the AVR processor? I assume that making it work for a certain instruction set requires a lot of tuning, that might have been done poorly?

Comment: @Jot I also posted this question to the people at Arduino.cc, lets see what they have to say. Maybe it is a GCC issue, or maybe an Arduino specific issue. https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=607719.0

Answer (score -1):

In my "local.h" file - macros & other definitions I tend to use a lot, just such as one you're asking about - I keep this one:

```
// Don't compile this function inline
//   '__NOINLINE void foo(void){ ... }'
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define __NOINLINE  __attribute__ ((noinline))
#else
#define NOINLINE error 'NOINLINE' not defined for this compiler
#endif
```

which both gives me a fairly simple way to invoke no-inlining, and a warning if I try to use it with a compiler for which I haven't defined its use. You don't really need the macro; you could use the gcc-dependent syntax - I just favor a simpler (and portable) symbol that could be defined for any compiler's no-inline syntax.

Comment: Great idea. I was thinking of doing the same to avoid the ugly noinline attribute string.

Comment: Would the drive-by down-voter care edify the rest of us with his/her reasons why this answer fails to address "Any idea how to prevent function inlining?"